# Generating assets from illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, mobile, adobe-creative-suite

I'm using PNG Express to extract asset from Photoshop. Is there any supporting plugin for Adobe illustrator to extract the assets?

Comment: Please refrain from asking two (entirely) different questions in one post, as the answers might be unclear. Could you split them up into two posts?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use any extra plugins to export .pngs in Illustrator.  I've found that using a single large artboard and creating named slices work well to export multiple .pngs.  Simply create the slices you want and then use <kbd>File > Save for Web</kbd> and either leave <kbd>All slices</kbd> selected or choose the slices you want.

I then optimise the exported files for the best performance using ImageOptim on Mac or FileOptimizer on Windows.

Illustrator works nicely for mobile design as it can produce scalable .svgs, saving a lot of hassle working with various high dpi screens.

Answer (score 0):

Illustrator has an "Unembed" feature that will extract a source image in its original resolution as either a PSD or Tiff. "Unembed" appears in the control panel when the image is selected, or from the Links pallet flyout menu. You can then batch convert the images to PNG if you like.

Comment: Can you explain in detail about asset extraction and batch convert

Comment: The particulars of unembedding has already been covered by the pros here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/unembed-images.html

Batch processing to different image types is covered here:
https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/processing-batch-files.html